# Hibernate: How to get results of a complex query into list of one class

Tags: hibernate

I have a complex query like below

```
Select a.CustomerName, total = sum(b.count), tot1 = (c.count) from customer a, xyz b, stp c where <lots of joins, sub Queries, etc >
```

I need the results into the instances of a class like

```
class CustomerTotal {
    String customerName;
    Integer total;
    Integer total1;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve the above.

thanks

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select-clause

Answer (score 0):

You can use here `AliasToBeanResultTransformer`
Result transformer that allows to transform a result to a user specified class which will be populated via setter methods or fields matching the alias names.

Your query will like:

```
List<CustomerTotal> resultWithAliasedBean = s.createCriteria(Customer.class)
                     add here your required joins
                        .setProjection( Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.property("a.CustomerName"), "customerName")
            .add(Projections.sum("b.count"), "total")
            .add(Projections.property("b.count"), "total1")
                        .setResultTransformer( new AliasToBeanResultTransformer(CustomerTotal.class) )
                        .list();
```

here is doc of [AliasToBeanResultTransforme](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/transform/AliasToBeanResultTransformer.html)